# HttpClientHandler RFC 7616 Digest Authentication Header Using Wrong Uri

Tags: c#, http, httpclient, flurl

I'm trying to access a resource on a Lighttpd server which enforces that the full request URI matches the URI in the Authorization request header.  This is specified in [RFC 7616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616#section-3.4.6)

> The authenticating server MUST assure that the resource designated
> by the "uri" parameter is the same as the resource specified in the
> Request-Line; if they are not, the server SHOULD return a 400 Bad
> Request error.  (Since this may be a symptom of an attack, server
> implementers may want to consider logging such errors.)  The purpose
> of duplicating information from the request URL in this field is to
> deal with the possibility that an intermediate proxy may alter the
> client's Request-Line.  This altered (but presumably semantically
> equivalent) request would not result in the same digest as that
> calculated by the client.

I'm using the [Flurl library](https://flurl.io/) (v1.4), which is just a wrapper around HttpClient. However, HttpClientHandler is from .Net.

Why does it use the base URI and not the full URI? Is it a bug? How do I make it use the full URI?

I thought of adding another *HttpMessageHandler* into the pipeline and modifying the *Authentication* header with the full URI, but *HttpClientHandler* doesn't let you set an *InnerHandler*.

The full **Uri should be**:
http://base/resource.cgi?my=1&params=2

But this is what appears in the request header:

> Authorization: Digest
> username="user",realm="serve",nonce="5b911545:eaf4352d2113e5e4b1ca253bd70fd90a",
> **uri="/base/resource.cgi"**,cnonce="bf7cf40f1289bc10bd07e8bf4784159c",nc=00000001,qop="auth",response="cf3c731ec93f7e5928f19f880f8325ab"

Which **results in a 400 Bad Request** response.

**My Flurl Code:**

**HttpClient Factory**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom factory to generate HttpClient and handler to use digest authentication and a continuous stream
    /// </summary>
    private class DigestHttpFactory : Flurl.Http.Configuration.DefaultHttpClientFactory
    {
        private CredentialCache CredCache { get; set; }

        public DigestHttpFactory(string url, string username, string password) : base()
        {
            Url = url;

            CredCache = new CredentialCache
            {
                { new Uri(Url), "Digest", new NetworkCredential(username, password) }
            };
        }

        private string Url { get; set; }

        public override HttpClient CreateHttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler)
        {
            var client = base.CreateHttpClient(handler);
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite); // To keep stream open indefinietly
            return client;
        }

        public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = CredCache.GetCredential(new Uri(Url), "Digest")
            };


            return handler;
        }
    }
```

**Request code**

```
public class MyConnection
{
    public string BaseUrl => "http://base/resource.cgi";

    public async Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ConnectionCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var url = BaseUrl
            .SetQueryParam("my", 1)
            .SetQueryParam("params", 2)

        FlurlHttp.ConfigureClient(url, client =>
        {
            client.Configure(settings =>
            {
                settings.HttpClientFactory = new DigestHttpFactory(url, Username, Password);
            });
        });

        try
        {
            using (var getResponse = url.GetAsync(cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                var responseMessage = await getResponse;

                using (var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ConnectionCancellation.Token, cancellationToken))
                using (var stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    await Process(stream, linkedCts.Token);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is indeed a [bug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/daniem/2013/02/27/digest-authentication-in-system-net-classes-dont-fully-comply-with-rfc2617/) with Microsoft's implementation of the RFC:

> System.Net classes don't include the query string in the 'Uri'
>   attribute of the digest authentication header. This is a violation of
>   the RFC, and some web server implementations reject those requests.

That post details a work-around taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3117042/62600).

Comment: Ah, was hoping I didn't have to reimplement the Digest Authentication. Considering its such an old issue, doubt Microsoft will do anything. Do you think you could add such a fix to your awesome library :)?  perhaps as an extra parameter of sorts for a more conservative approach, or perhaps I could add it in some pull request?

Comment: I won't make any promises but go ahead and [log](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/new) it, and please link back this question. People are asking for Windows auth as well, so maybe I can knock both out in some future release.