# .Net Core HttpClient Digest Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, digest-authentication

Working with the Mongo Atlas API in a .Net Core 3.1 application, but I cannot get `HttpClient` to handle the challenge from Digest Authentication.

The code sends the first request, gets a 401 response, and then doesn't resend with proper authentication.

Below is the code I've been trying to get working

```cs
var domain = "https://cloud.mongodb.com/";
var credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add(new Uri(domain),"Digest", new NetworkCredential(user,secret));
var httpClient = new HttpClient( new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credCache});
var answer = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri($"{domain}api/atlas/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/databaseUsers"));
```

Here's the response I'm getting

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 21:03:14 GMT
  WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="MMS Public API", domain="", nonce="generatedNonce", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth", stale=false
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 106
}
```

I've sent curl requests successully so I'm certain my user/secret/group are correct.

Does anyone see something wrong with that code, or know what I can do to further debug this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently we have the exact same problem or I had at least until my colleague found a solution for it.

There was a lot of changes to HttpClient internals in 2.1 to support the new SocketsHttpHandler, use this line of code to go back to the 2.0 functionality and it should work again, put it `Main` or somewhere before the calls you are making.

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

Otherwise you'd have to first send one request get the `401` response grab the `nonce` from the `WwwAuthenticate` header and you probably also need to set some more fields in the header.

Cheers!

Found it in this post on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/9yailz/weird_dotnet_core_httpclient_bug_maybe/ea07edd/

Comment: This workaround is no longer working in .Net 5, has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I ended up creating a custom handler similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109507/httpwebrequests-sends-parameterless-uri-in-authorization-header

Comment: @Eric you should post the handler if it worked for you no ?

Comment: If anyone else is looking for a more in detail answer to this will a full implementation, I made a blog post to show how it can be done 'from scratch': 
https://dev.to/callumhoughton18/implementing-digest-authentication-in-net-396j

Comment: I just copy pasted all the methods in @CallumHoughton 's link and got it to work, nice 1!